# How do i use JavaScript evaluate() in an Android WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, evaluate

I want to create a calculator which is able to evaluate Strings like 3+(2-1)*2 or (28.4/2-1.5)+(4-2). I searched the web and found the possibility to use a WebView with JavaScript enabled which can evaluate() Strings.

How do i use JavaScript in a WebView?

How can i pass for example input.getText().toString() to the JavaScript and get back a value?

How do i access evaluate() of JavaScript in my Java-code?

I found a tutorial [here](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.de/2011/09/android-javascriptinterface-tutorial.html). I have to load the HTML-file into my WebView, don't i?

Answer (score -1):

You are going right. For using javascript in webview, after you load url to webview,(you can catch to page loading done at onPageFinish function) at onPageFinish function, you call js like this:

But first you must give permission to webview with these code blocks:

```
   settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

   webview.loadUrl("javascript:setPageHeight("+contentHeight+");"); // you can pass param with call js function at loaded page.
   webview.loadUrl("javascript:alert('test');"); // or you can call like this
```

For take result param from webview with js you must a subclass like this:

```
   class JavaScriptInterface {
      public void showToast(String msg) {
           Toast.makeText(mContext, "Received Msg :" + msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   }
```

Then you give this to your webview at the define webview lines

```
   webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "MyAndroid");
```

Finally you call java function in your html in js like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function sayHello(msg){
        //calls Android's JavaScriptInterface Function
        MyAndroid.showToast(msg);
      }
    </script>
 </head>
 <body >
   <div onclick="sayHello('hello')"> Click Me !!  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```